# time stamp missing when batch file ran from Windows Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, timestamp

I have a very simple batch file

```
@SET isodt=%DATE:~6,4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%_%TIME::=-%
DatabaseCleansing.Process.exe > output\output_%isodt%.txt
```

When ran manually it creates file names like so

> output_2016-06-09_23-29-47.44.txt

However when ran automatically by the Windows Scheduler it creates a filename like this:

> output_2016-06-10_

The contents of the file is correct in both cases.
Any guesses as to what I've done wrong?

Comment: use quotes around the outputfile: `>"output\output_%isodt%.txt" (see @JosefZ's answer for explanation). Although I'd prefer Josefs locale independent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
rem get CIM_DATETIME
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in (
  'wmic OS get localdatetime /value') do set "ldt=%%G"

rem simplified format yyyymmddHHMMSS.mm e.g. 20160610160046.36
set "isodt=%ldt:~0,17%"
echo simplified format yyyymmddHHMMSS.mm %isodt%

rem modified ISO format yyyy-mm-dd_HH-MM-SS.mm e.g. 2016-06-10_16-00-46.36
set "isodt=%ldt:~0,4%-%ldt:~4,2%-%ldt:~6,2%_%ldt:~8,2%-%ldt:~10,2%-%ldt:~12,5%"
echo modified ISO format yyyy-mm-dd_HH-MM-SS.mm %isodt%

rem use quotes around the output file (thanks for the thought, Stephan)
DatabaseCleansing.Process.exe > "output\output_%isodt%.txt"
```

**Explanation**: your script would work as expected if run between `10:00:00` and `23:59:59`. However, `%time%` variable contains a **leading space** between `00:00:00` and `09:59:59`.

This behaviour occurs despite of next time format settings

```
==> reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\International" | findstr /I "sTimeFormat sShortTime"
    sTimeFormat    REG_SZ    HH:mm:ss
    sShortTime     REG_SZ    HH:mm
```

although `HH` there should display the hour with a leading zero; compare what the [Change the display of dates, times, currency, and measurements](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-dates-times-currency-measurements-display) article says:

> Select the date and time formats that you want to use. Windows uses
>   the following notations to specify how dates and times are displayed:
>
> ```
> Time notations  Displays
> --------------  --------
> h               Hour (hh displays the hour with a leading zero)
> m               Minute (mm displays the minute with a leading zero)
> s               Second (ss displays the second with a leading zero)
> h/H             12 or 24 hour time display
> ```

Use

```
@SET "isodt=%DATE:~6,4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%_%TIME::=-%"
@SET "isodt=%isodt: =0%"
```

or better, obtain `%isodt%` variable from **locale independent** [CIM_DATETIME `yyyymmddHHMMSS.mmmmmmsUUU` format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387237(v=vs.85).aspx). For instance, you could modify [next code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36742410/3439404) to add hyphens and underscores:

```
rem obtain %datetime% variable in locale independent yyyymmddHHMMSS format
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in (
  'wmic OS get localdatetime /value') do set "datetime=%%G"
set "isodt=%datetime:~0,17%"
```

Moreover, `SET "isodt=%DATE:~6,4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%_%TIME::=-%"` command could *fail* as well returning `. 20- 0-10_15-22-11,63` under next short date format setting which was undesirably preinstalled by default for my Windows 8.1 original system locale as a space *allegedly* should follow after any full stop by wrongly interpreted [Czech language grammar rules](http://prirucka.ujc.cas.cz/en/?id=160#nadpis10):

```
==> reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /V sShortDate

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International
    sShortDate    REG_SZ    dd. MM. yyyy
```

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense I'll give that a go